# Does using multiple batteries (via grip) improve AF speed?

Tags: autofocus, battery, battery-grip

I want to say I read somewhere that, particularly with heavier lenses (such as the 70-200 F/2.8), having two batteries in the portrait grip would provide extra juice to the AF motor and help it achieve focus faster. Can anyone confirm if this is accurate?

Comment: Never knew this. Good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely dependent on the make/model of the DSLR. Some ONLY use the extra battery power as reserve, while others will register the availability of the extra power and drive the AF motor more vigorously.

But this is brand/make/model specific.

Comment: Also, some Nikon bodies allow a faster maximum burst rate when a battery grip is attached.

Comment: How would one find out for my particular camera (currently a 60d, but hopefully will change one day)?

Comment: @tenmiles if the feature is available, the manual for the camera should indicate this. If it doesn't, then it won't.